# Unable to fetch broker ID using kubectl command

Tags: kubernetes, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, kubectl, kubernetes-helm

I want to fetch the list of broker ids in a cluster using kubectl exec command.

I am able to run the commands from inside the pod and fetch the list of broker ids, however I need to find the list without having to go inside.

I am using kafka [helm charts from incubator](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/incubator/kafka) and Kubernetes distribution which comes along with docker for Mac.

```
kubectl exec hissing-warthog-kafka-1 -- /usr/bin/zookeeper-shell hissing-warthog-zookeeper:2181 <<< "ls /brokers/ids"
```

**Expected result:**
Welcome to ZooKeeper!
JLine support is enabled

WATCHER::

WatchedEvent state:SyncConnected type:None path:null
[zk: hissing-warthog-zookeeper:2181(CONNECTED) 0] ls /brokers/ids
[0, 1, 2]

**Actual result:**
Connecting to hissing-warthog-zookeeper:2181
Welcome to ZooKeeper!
JLine support is enabled

WATCHER::

WatchedEvent state:SyncConnected type:None path:null
[zk: hissing-warthog-zookeeper:2181(CONNECTED) 0]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should work in following way:

```
kubectl exec hissing-warthog-kafka-1 -- /usr/bin/zookeeper-shell hissing-warthog-zookeeper:2181 -c ls /brokers/ids
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Worked. Thanks. Could you tell me the significance of "-c" though?